# Python - module 'x' has no attribute 'y' - Circular reference's

Tags: python

I have 2 .py files, one which does all the calculations and another which handles the inputs and outputs essentially doing the front end side. (one called BackEnd, the other called FrontEnd)

But receive the following error message

```
  File "C:\Users\ABour\Python Scripts\test\FrontEnd.py", line 23, in Outputs
    x = BE.Outputs('dtext')

AttributeError: module 'BackEnd' has no attribute 'Outputs'
```

Any help in solving this would be gretaly appreciated.

The values a-c declared in FrontEnd.py are inputted to BackEnd.py via a function, calculations are done with them and the outputs d-g are outputted to FrontEnd.py via another function

```
#BackEnd.py
def Inputs(x):

    import FrontEnd as FE

    if x == 'AC_LK':
            x = FE.Inputs('atext')

    elif x == 'AC_HK':
            x = FE.Inputs('btext')

    elif x == 'P_Tot':
            x = FE.Inputs('ctext')

a =  Inputs('atext')
b = Inputs('btext')
c = Inputs('ctext') # Bara


d = 4
e = 5
f = 6
g = 7

def Outputs(x):
    if x == 'dtext':
        x = d

    elif x == 'etext':
        x = e

    elif x == 'ftext':
        x = f

    elif x == 'gtext':
        x = g

    return x
```

I then have the following code in FrontEnd.py

```
#FrontEnd.py

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

def Inputs(x):

    if x == 'atext':
            x = a

    elif x == 'btext':
            x = b

    elif x == 'ctext':
            x = c


def Outputs(x):

    import BackEnd as BE

    if x == 'dtext':
        x = BE.Outputs('dtext')

    elif x == 'etext':
        x = BE.Outputs('etext')

    elif x == 'ftext':
        x = BE.Outputs('ftext')

    elif x == 'gtext':
        x = BE.Outputs('gtext')

    return x

dvalue = Outputs('dtext')
print('dtext = ',dvalue)
```

Comment: I couldn't replicate this, I get the expected `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`. Check your spelling and make sure the code you've presented here is **exactly** the same code. Following your edit, I'm now getting the result `Number of Plates =  1`

Comment: @NickA it is not a executable.

Comment: Please be sure Eqm and Inputs are in same directory.

Comment: I originally used excerpts nick as I assumed it was something to do with the way I'd formatted this section, I have added some values for a-d now and both files will have to be saved as seperate .py files

Comment: @Ayrton Can you show us the importing part?

Comment: It imports within the function to avoid circular referencing elsewhere in the code

Comment: @Pavan the import is inside the `Inputs.Outputs` definition

Comment: @NickA I meant that the code present here is not a minimum code to replicate the behaviour.

Comment: Apologies I see what you mean, just tried them as these two on their won and it worked perfectly, the issue must be elsewhere in my code

Comment: @Pavan I have edited the question so that you should be able to replicate the error with just these sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with circular dependency, by adding `if __name__ == '__main__':` before code which ran functions which referred to the other file

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

def Inputs(x):

    if x == 'atext':
            x = a

    elif x == 'btext':
            x = b

    elif x == 'ctext':
            x = c

def Outputs(x):

    import BackEnd as BE

    if x == 'dtext':
        x = BE.Outputs('dtext')

    elif x == 'etext':
        x = BE.Outputs('etext')

    elif x == 'ftext':
        x = BE.Outputs('ftext')

    elif x == 'gtext':
        x = BE.Outputs('gtext')

    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dvalue = Outputs('dtext')
    print('dtext = ',dvalue)
```